# Command 'npm install -g firebase-tool' gets stuck during installation on MacOS Ventura

Tags: firebase, npm, firebase-tools

Trying to install `firebase-tools` using the command `npm install -g firebase-tool` but it's stuck here

```
idealTree:morgan: MOOD DlaceDep node_modules/firebase—tools on—finished@2.4.1 OK for: body—parser@1.20.2 want: 2.4.1
```

Comment: Did you try with: --loglevel verbose?

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please [don't show pictures of text and code](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/formatting-text-code#dont-use-screenshots-of-text). Copy the text into the question itself and format it so that it's easy to read, copy, and search. You can edit the question to correct this using the edit link at the bottom.

Comment: done @DougStevenson